# Changing background color of a section in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is it possible to set the background color of a section of a UITableView. 
I want to set the background color of one section to "UIColor clearColor".
When I did, its showing the transparent section with border. How can I prevent the border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `separatorStyle` property of your `UITableView` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone` and draw borders inside your cells. Add and position 1px UIView and hide it when you don't need the border to be shown.